# waitForTransform Issues and errors

Tags: ros-melodic, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to have my code use the

`self.listener.waitForTransform(from_frame, to_frame, rtn, rospy.Duration(0.5))`  and `TransformPoint` to transform points around my robot from map to base_scan frame, as the robot moves. In order to get this to work I have to use the same time stamp for each run so that every point around the robot at any given time  gets the same exact transform information to use for the transform calculation.

So this is the psuedocode of how I tried to make this work.

def transform(self,coord,from_frame='map',to_frame='base_scan',rtn=None):
if rtn is None:
rtn=rospy.get_rostime()
self.scope.header.frame_id = from_frame
self.scope.header.stamp = rtn # rospy.TIme(0)
self.scope.point.x = coord[0]
self.scope.point.y = coord[1]
self.scope.point.z = 0

```
    try:
        self.listener.waitForTransform(from_frame, to_frame, rtn, rospy.Duration(0.5))
        p = self.listener.transformPoint(to_frame, self.scope)
        return [p.point.x,p.point.y]
    except (tf.LookupException, tf.ConnectivityException, tf.ExtrapolationException):
        raise

def use_transform():
points=gather all points around robot at any given time
rtn=rospy.get_rostime() 
for point in points:
transform(point,rtn) from map to base scan
........
```

When I run this code I get this below:

```
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tf/listener.py", line 74, in waitForTransform
    can_transform, error_msg = self._buffer.can_transform(strip_leading_slash(target_frame), strip_leading_slash(source_frame), time, timeout, return_debug_tuple=True)
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tf/listener.py", line 45, in strip_leading_slash
    return s[1:] if s.startswith("/") else s
AttributeError: 'Time' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

Is it because I'm using rospy.get_rostime()? Should I be using something else? I've tries rospy.Time(0), rospy.Time.now() and have the same issue. I have searched the `listener.py` script the error talks about. I have no diea waht I should change in the script to fix this error.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/398511/waitfortransform-issues-and-errors/) by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2022-04-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's not related to how you constructed your time object. From the error it looks like you're passing a `Time` object where it's expecting a string frame_id. As it's trying to strip a potentially leading slash from the frame_id. You should make sure to check your arguments that you're inputting to the functions.

There's presumably truncated backtrace information above the section that you've quoted which will show you your problem.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2022-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1